# align center and bottom vertically inside a grid element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid of two elements - `childa` and `childb`.

`childb` has its own `inside` child which I cannot `center vertically` and place `bottom vertically`.

Any help?

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  height: 170px;
  background: black;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  background: gold;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.inside {
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child childa'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child childb'>
    <div class='inside'>
      sdfsdfsdfd<br> adfdsfsdds
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .childb { display: flex;  align-items: flex-end;} Is it what yor're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not looking for a grid-only solution, I believe flexbox functionalities can help you achieve what you want.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a great source for this.

```
.childb {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Edit: you can edit the values (such as **center**) as you wish by looking into the link above.

Comment: He said 'bottom-vertically' as well. That's why I'm not sure about what he wants

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after sending my post. Edited so that whoever needs to can look up a solution in the css-tricks tutorial.